# Re-write only the root to a holding folder?

Tags: .htaccess

I am currently developing a website and have a holding page in a /hold folder.  However I have my Wordpress installation in the root too.

What I want is that if a user goes to:

```
www.domain.com
```

They get forwarded to:

> www.domain.com/hold

However if someone goes to www.domain.com/index.php it loads Wordpress instead.  That way, I can still work on Wordpress by going to /index.php and anyone who visits the site normally see's the holding page.

I currently have this in my .htaccess:

```
# Set a default home directory, (this subfolder always loads)
# Replace 'folder' with your subfolder name
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /hold/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# Always use www in the domain
# Replace 'example.com' with your domain name
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)?domain\.com$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
#RewriteRule .? http://www.%1domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this without resorting to `mod_rewrite`. How about:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://www.yourdomain.com/hold/
```

See [the `RedirectMatch` documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch).

However you may be better off setting up a second virtualhost, so you can put your entire public site into holding (using something like `RewriteRule ^.*$ /hold/ [R=503,L]` to get the 503 HTTP status code) but still use the Wordpress admin and site yourself through a different hostname. (I don't know if Wordpress will have problems with doing that; I have a feeling its insistence on knowing the domain it runs under may cause you problems, sadly.)

(I suspect you're running into problems because your first `RewriteRule` assumes `RewriteBase /` will already have happened, although it's been a while since I used `RewriteBase`, and the documentation isn't clear on this. For such a simple pair of cases I'd avoid `RewriteBase` completely to avoid confusion.)